# Virtual Files for dynamic linking

Tags: c++, file, dynamic, linker, virtual

my problem is pretty complicated and potentially impossible but here we go:

Using C++,
I'm currently working on an universal server engine for a game project of mine. Universal, because every part of the engine will be loaded dynamically after startup. Now, also game objects will inherit from a base object and have overloaded "Simulate" functions. In that way, every object would have it's specific behavior and I can do something I call "C++ Scripting" which is alot faster than interpreted lua script files. Also it's more dynamic.
(Please no solutions which would kill the c++ "scripting" part, like "forget the dynamic linking, that's insane". This performance boost is totally necessary, since I'm working with large voxel maps)

My Problem:

That are indeed alot of *.dll/*.so files and I wanted to pack those into a simple archive so I can use zlib on said source code and maybe pack everything together with textures and sounds in little "object packages".
Now the Windows DLL API and the Linux SO API won't allow me to load a dll/so file from a memory address, which is a shame.(Am I right there, or can I bypass that? :) ) I don't want to unzip and temp save those files on the filesystem because there are hundreds to thousands of them and that would increase the loading time alot.
Also I'm not interested in more external dependencies like boost.

So here are my Questions:

Is there a cross platform-method to create virtual files IN memory with a real path?
That way I could bypass the slow IO speeds of HDDs.

Or is it really not such a big deal to use temp files, because the file buffers of modern operating systems are fast/intelligent enough to NOT write all those files to disc?
(Actually Linux supports virtual file systems, but windows does not...)

I hope you guys can help me there :)

Comment: Why not just have them expanded on disk as regular files? They'll just be mapped into memory from the disk. Even if you could create the modules in memory, unless you lock the pages they are eligible to swap to disk anyway. At that point there's no real performance difference between the two so just go with the simple way.

Comment: If I put everything on disc I would end up with directories filled with 1000+ dll's and so files. Windows searches though directories pretty supid and I would get alot of file system overhead, in the end slowing down everything.
Also my "object archive package thing" wouldn't work, then. : /

Comment: I'm pretty sure trying to load 1000+ dll/so is not going to go well regardless of what method you use to load them.

Comment: I did some tests with artificial objects (2048; random created code with different attributes) and a little test octree engine using the dynamic linking for block/cell-types. (with the dlls in a folder) and it ran awesomely fast. so loading a chunkload of dynamic code is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with winapi, that's for sure, but you can do it manually. You can load it into the memory, fill it's import table and call exported functions (after you called DllMain). I saw a program, where someone actually created a new process with that method ... See the PE documentation for details, but it works.

Also it's relatively easy to do, since you only need to find the PE import tables, and do what the dynamic linker does, fill it with jumps and addresses. Dlls contains position independent code, so no relocation needed.

It sould be the same on linux (only using the elf structure), but if you have a better solution with virtual file systems, you should use that.

Comment: Windows (since vista) prevents data execution in memory. In the end I would get an segmentation fault if I try to run pointers which lead to allocated data memory. it is possible to disable that feature, but that creates a nice little security thread for self altering viruses. Also it's pretty complicated to disable said feature. *Nothing you could do in a simple install script/setup.

Comment: @Alzurana: No, Vista does not prevent data execution.  If it did, JTI compilers in Java and .NET could not work.  Rather, it prevents accidental execution, which was a common security flaw (return to scriptcode buffer overflow attacks).  You can still call `VirtualProtect` and mark the page as executable.

Comment: last time i tried i could copy a function and execute it in win 7 with malloc.

Comment: Good to know. In that case I will try it. Linux has virtual file systems build in (/dev/shm <- originally for process exchange) so I got my answer. Thank you very much, I was going crazy because of that issue.